# here comes/there goes-like structures

Tags: exclamatives

When I read the present simple unit I came across with the Present Simple structure. There was ***here comes***, ***there goes***, etc. The Present Progressive tense is unacceptable in such structures (like ***here is coming***). Could you get another examples of such structures?

Note: That I don't mean ***stative*** verb like promise, swear, etc which is also unacceptable to use Present Progressive. I want to understand what exactly such structures denote.

Comment: Can you rewrite the question making it simple to understand!

Comment: @MaulikV Is there any constructions like _here comes_, _there goes_ where Present Progressive is unacceptable?

Comment: But I don't understand the structure. I have come across this -*here (?) comes ... or there (?) goes* But here where is the word replacing '?' Remember, in such structures, pronoun subjects ***always come directly after 'here' and 'there'***

Comment: @MaulikV This pattern ("Here comes X", "There goes Z") is common in English. For Dmitry Fucintv, I've never seen or heard this pattern in the progressive before. (Very likely ungrammatical.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'd not prefer it that way. As I said, I'd put *pronoun subjects* directly after *here/there*. So, *There she is* over *There is she*.

Comment: @MaulikV I think you mixed up several patterns together. First, "There she is" is not what the OP asked about. (The OP asked specifically about *comes* and *goes*.) Second, the OP haven't mentioned anything about pronouns; it was you who took this pattern in the context of pronouns. Third, as I said, "Here comes X" is common, e.g. *Here comes the bride*. I dare say that "Here the bride comes" is not as good.

Comment: @DamkerngT. That's why I did not post that as an answer. The question is unclear. And about *bride* example, you are not using a pronoun subject so what I said does not apply. But what do you think he wants to say? *Here comes/There goes!*

Comment: @MaulikV The OP said that the OP "read the present simple unit" and "There was here comes, there goes, etc". Given the context is a grammar book, it's only reasonable to think that the OP referred to "Here comes X", "There goes X", and so on. It's also likely that the book might cover the inversion for pronouns and might mention a phrase such as "Here we go (again)" or "Here you are", too.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes! Could you provide another example of such structures besides _there goes_ and _here comes_?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's very difficult to think of other verbs being used this way. (Apart from idiomatic usage such as "Here it is", "Here you are", and so on.) The only one I could come up with at the moment is "Here lies X".

Comment: @DamkerngT. Many thanks. I just wanted to know a bit more examples. :)

Comment: This might help, it has more examples: http://www.eslhq.com/forums/esl-forums/english-questions/here-comes-bus-so-am-i-16813/

Comment: @fluffy You found it! Please post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Here/There comes/is/goes X* is not an ordinary declarative sentence like *X is VERBing here/there* but an exclamatory idiom, typically employed to draw the hearer's attention to the arrival, presence, or departure of someone or something noteworthy. The canonical sentence is rearranged to put the subject in the ‘new information’ position at the end of the sentence, where its head takes the sentence’s primary emphasis.

> Heads up, people! Here comes *the train*!
>   And now—h e e e r e’s ***Johnny!***
>   Oh, hell, here comes *the boss*. I gotta get back to work.
>   It’s completely busted. I can’t fix it. There goes *our deadline*.
>   There, but for the grace of God, go ***I***.

The idiom occasionally uses other verbs of motion (or stillness):

> There walks *the vilest desperado in Abilene*.
>   There lies *the bravest woman I have ever met*.

When the subject is a pronoun, which is necessarily ‘old information’, it precedes the verb, so it is the verb which is emphasized.

> Here we *go*! —*said on departure, or on starting an endeavor*

A classic example is the cry of the lookout on old whaling vessels, announcing his sighting of a whale ‘blowing’:

> Thar she *blows*!